# Dynamically Added HTML With Animated Positioning

Tags: php, html, css

Ok, this is quite a tedious one.

Essentially, I have a file, "thedot". My PHP script reads from this file and splits it out into the 3 sections, called dots. It then renders the dots to the page, in rows of three, formatted with CSS and filled with the content from the file.

Easy enough so far. But, these dots are weirdly animated. They are black normally, you can't see their content. When you hover over them, they expand, and change colour so that you can.
My problem is that when I render them out, hovering over each one causes all the others to move.

I have tried:
a) Using position:fixed on the dots and using the PHP to assign them specific positions. This didn't work since hovering over them caused them to expand from the top left corner, when I need them to expand from the centre.
b) Using individual tables for each row. This still pushed the rest down.
c) Using auto margins. This had no effect.

Live site (looking hideous) at tuxnet.co.uk/dots/browse

Example of intended effect (only one, not a column of them): tuxnet.co.uk/dots/dot?dot=18668

Cheers,

Freddy.

P.S. When hovering over a dot in a row, it is okay if the other two members of that row are moved horizontally, as in the single row example.

Comment: The height of each row is fit to the size of the tallest element, so the row will have to increase its height when the circle expands, which leads to all of rows moving. Have you tried increasing the height of the rows to accomodate for the enlarged circle, so that the row does not need to expand once the circle has expanded?

Comment: @Freddy Tuxworth I am not very much sure but you may need to replace TABLE with DIV tags because all the column (TD of each row) are getting expanded because the content of any TD is getting bigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answer makes any sense, but I'll take a swing.

I would try using `position:relative` on the `<td>` tags. Then use `position:absolute` on the child dots.

`position:absolute` allows an element to position itself either according to the next parent element with `position:absolute/relative` or to `<html>` if it cannot find any parent of that nature. Because you would be using `position:absolute`, you should not run into problems with elements being "pushed" by other elements; however, you could run into some overlapping issues (which can be solved easily using z-index).

I hope that helps!

EDIT:
I fiddled with your css file linked to your demo page. Let me know if this is what you were looking for. The only changes made were in `td` and `.dot`

```
td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  height:70px;
  width:70px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.dot {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
  font-family: "courier new";
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #000000;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  max-width: 70px;
  max-height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
          transition: all 0.3s;
}

.dot:hover {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  max-width: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  top:-35px;
  left:-35px;
  z-index:1;
}

.one:hover {
  background-color: #AA11FF;
}
.two:hover {
  background-color: #11AAFF;
}
.three:hover {
  background-color: #FFAA11;
}
.onedex {
  background-color: #AA11FF;
}
.twodex {
  background-color: #11AAFF;
}
.threedex {
  background-color: #FFAA11;
}

.footer {
font-size: 10;
font-family: 'courier new';
position: fixed;
bottom: 15px;
width: 100px;
left: 50%;
margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
text-align: center;
}

.header {
font-size: 30;
font-family: 'courier new';
position: fixed;
top: 25%;
width: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: 0 0 0 -25%;
text-align: center;
}
.sharer {
font-size: 20;
font-family: 'courier new';
position: fixed;
bottom: 25%;
width: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: 0 0 0 -25%;
text-align: center;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  font-family: "courier new";
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "courier new";
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #11AAFF;
  color: #11AAFF;
}

.dotstatic {
  font-family: "courier new";
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.error {
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "courier new";
  color: #E01B1B;
}

.divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Also please note that css transitions are not supported by IE versions 9 and earlier. If you are attempting to make this web page work cross-browser, you may want to consider using JQuery to help with the hover animations.

Comment: Sorry! I only just realised this answer had come in. I'll check that out.

Comment: Awesome! This works really well! Now I just need to figure out how to stop the overlap, but a bit of margining should work. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work completely as per your requirement but hovering on Dot doesn't shift the dots of other rows. You will need to make more changes to work as per your expectation.

```
<div><!-- first Row -->
<div class="dot one" style="margin: auto;">test</div> 
<div class="dot two" style="margin: auto;">test</div> 
<div class="dot three" style="margin: auto;">test</div>
</div>
<div><!-- second Row -->
<div class="dot one" style="margin: auto;">test</div> 
<div class="dot two" style="margin: auto;">test</div> 
<div class="dot three" style="margin: auto;">test</div>
</div>
```